# No puedo convertir en System.Collection.Generic.List

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, entity-framework, linq

[image: Creacion de la clase que retorna los datos de la tabla]
[image: Formulario donde utilizo la clase]

Intento guardar los datos que obtengo de la consulta en un DataTable, pero me dice que no puedo convertir a System.Collections.Generic.List

Comment: Debes editar tu pregunta y añadir el código como texto en lugar de poner una captura de pantalla. Te recomiendo que leas [una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/)

Answer (score 1):

Para convertir una `List<>` a un datatable ya existe la funcionalidad en `.net` por medio del `CopyToDataTable<>()`

[Crear un objeto DataTable a partir de una consulta (LINQ to DataSet)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-datatable-from-a-query-linq-to-dataset)

No necesitas de ningun metodo Convert() que itere las propiedades para convertir en row.

---

Por otro lado tu problema se presenta porque la `query linq` esta retornando un `tipo anonimo` y no una clase concreta del tipo cliente, para ue esto sucesa deberias definir

```
var lis = (....
          select new cliente(){
             ...
          }).ToList();
```

veras que defino la clase en el `select new`